# Eclipse Kepler, "Java Build path"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in eclipse Kepler with Ubuntu 12.04, 
I have a problem when compile my proyect:

> Project 'PRIMAC' is missing required library: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'    PRIMAC      Build path  Build Path Problem

I try to add this Path manually, however, when I compile again, the compilation erase automatically this path (classes-full-debug.jar), help!

Comment: Wrong path ????

Comment: How did you add it manually?